# Drawing on a JPanel or frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I am currently coding a Java program that involves loading an image of a map on a JLabel. I would like to draw on this map image. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: 1) Override the paintComponent(...) method of the JLabel to add addition Graphics logic. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples. The tutorial draws on a JPanel, but the concept is the same. You first invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` to do the default painting of the label, then you add your custom code.

Comment: The two ways suggested by @camickr both work, but I usually use a third way that removes the need to extend either `JLabel` or `JPanel`. It basically goes like this: 1) Load the image of interest and store it as an attribute of the class. 2) Create a method that makes a copy of this image to display in a label contained in a panel. 3) On 'change' (e.g. the user dragging the mouse across a label to draw a line) adjust the drawing of the **copy** of the image before setting it as the `ImageIcon` of the label.